How to insert an attribute and value 'true' to a record and false to remaining records and records in other tables?
I have list of tables class1, class2, class3...Each has multiple records like department, student, subjects etc.
Student records have attributes USN, branch, age, DOB, phoneNo, isLeader, isPresident
isLeader = true if student is a class representative
isPresident = true if student is a President for student union
If I insert isPresident = true for one student from one class(table), all student records should be false(even from other classes because there are multiple classes, but studenti president is unique)
Once I insert isLeader = true to one record, other table/tables' isLeader values should be changed to 'false'.
I'm using dynamoDB, lambda function with Python for coding.

I have reframed my requirements

I got it resolved using client.list_tables()
below is the code:
import json
import boto3
from boto3 import resource

# Initialize the DynamoDB client
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
resource = resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get a list of all table names
    response = client.list_tables()

    # String to search for
    # search_string = 'rest1'

    # List to store tables containing the search string
    matching_tables = []

    # Check each table name for the search string
    for table_name in response['TableNames']:

        if "rest1" in table_name:
            matching_tables.append(table_name)
            print("Aline23 matching_tables",matching_tables)

        
            #Updating rest1_localrest3
            if table_name == "rest1_localrest3":
                print("Aline35 table_name isDefault will be true: ",table_name)
                table = resource.Table(table_name)
                response = table.update_item(
                    Key = {'PK':'restindividual#restaccountinfo', 'SK': 'restaccountinfo'},
                    UpdateExpression = "SET isDefault = :s",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues = {':s' : True},
                    )                
            #Updating restaurants other than rest1_localrest3
            else:
                print("Aline35 table_name isDefault will be false: ",table_name)
                table = resource.Table(table_name)
                response = table.update_item(
                    Key = {'PK':'restindividual#restaccountinfo', 'SK': 'restaccountinfo'},
                    UpdateExpression = "SET isDefault = :s",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues = {':s' : False},
                    )            


    # Return the list of matching table names
    return {
        'body': json.dumps('Updated successfully')
    }


You have to first read every item in the table, then iterate through the results using UpdateItem.
For items where it should be false, set it as that. And for the item that should be true, set it to true.

Read all items using Scan
Iterate through the results
Based on the item, set the attribute to either true or false


I have this idea, but don't know to how to implement it

If you don't know how to code it, you can get examples here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python
